# Rails 5 API accepts_nested_attributes_for not works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I'm trying to save an event with tasks using accepts_nested_attributes_for but it doesn't work.

My models:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event, optional: true
end
```

Event params method

```
params.require(:event).permit(:name, tasks_attributes: [ :name ])
```

Post call

```
{
    "name": "event",
    "tasks_attributes": [
        { "name": "Task 1" }    
    ]
}
```

What do you think that can be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bruno!

You actually have to use an envelope for the object you're trying to post.

```
{
    "event": {
        "name": "event",
        "tasks_attributes": [
            { "name": "Task 1" }    
        ]
    }
}
```